# How to use PackageManager to retrieve dialer/browser/sms app etc?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I am writing a launcher and I need to find the dialer, browser, sms and camera app to put as shortcuts on the dock.

I assume different vendors like Samsung/HTC/Google will all have different apps for each of these with different package names.

Is there a way to use the PackageManager to get the default dialer app for example?

EDIT:

As per the advice given below I ended up implementing it like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = pm.resolveActivity(i, 0);
AppModel result = null;
if (resolveInfo != null) {
    ActivityInfo activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;
    if (activityInfo != null) {
        if ("android".equals(activityInfo.packageName)) {
            // no default activity.. choose first
            List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = m.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
            for (ResolveInfo rInfo : resolveInfos) {
                result = new AppModel(context, rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                break;
            }

        } else {
            ApplicationInfo appInfo = activityInfo.applicationInfo;
            if (appInfo != null) {
                result = new AppModel(context, appInfo);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `Intent` identifying what you want to do (e.g., an `ACTION_DIAL` `Intent` with a fake phone number), then use `PackageManager` and either `resolveActivity()` or `queryIntentActivities()`.

However, bear in mind that there may not *be* a default for those operations, for any number of reasons, including:

- The device is not a phone
- The user does not have rights to any matching app, courtesy of restricted profiles on Android 4.3+ devices
- The user may have installed 2+ apps for that `Intent`, and has not yet chosen a default (`resolveActivity()` will return the system chooser)

Also, the answer of what the default app is will change over time, just as you are hoping that the user's chosen home screen default app will change to be yours.