# Only display my image using defaul gallery app

Tags: java, android

I want to *only* open images in my app using the default gallery app. I have read others answers in the page but I haven't luck.

The following code works but it displays an image picker. I'd like to display it only using gallery app.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + pathToImageFile), "image/*");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ACTION_VIEW - a implicit intent so Android system will call any apps.You need to make your intent explicit. We have 2 solutions:

1. You know exactly Gallery package name such as com.sec.android.gallery3d or something like that - in Samsung phone. But it seems not smart
2. Call the default app for each action. You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710631/how-to-use-packagemanager-to-retrieve-dialer-browser-sms-app-etc/23710718#23710718)